# iOS pop up UI views

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, popup

I'm a beginner iOS dev and I can't seem to figure out how to create effects where if you press a button a UI view(like a date picker) pops up and the rest gets blurred out 
[image: before]
[image: with pop up]

Comment: That's setting the inputView of a specific UIResponder (read: field). The blurred effect is actually unnecessarily difficult to accomplish - Apple does it in a few places, but everything else is either using workarounds with the little bit Apple does allow developers to modify or essentially capturing the view and applying a blurred effect to the image and displaying it there.

Comment: How does one apply a blurred effect from within the application?

Answer (score 0):

Use [This](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNBlurModalView) with

Custom View option

```
RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self view:view];
[modal show];
```

Hope this would help you..